# jQuery TriggerHandler doesn't trigger keyup event set via live

Tags: jquery

Why i can't trigget handler via triggerHandler if it's was bound via live?

For example

```
  form.find('#code').live('change keyup',function(){
   process_code($(this));   
  });
```

Startups after window load:

```
   /* Triggers */
   if(checkCookie('banner_ready_code'))
   {
    $('#form').find('#code').triggerHandler('keyup');
   }
```

Nothing happens...

If i'm binding simply by .change or .keyup, triggerHandler is working properly as intended.

If it's bug, where to report it. Too lazy :)
If not, please explain. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug. `triggerHandler()` doesn't bubble the event, and `live()` relies on event bubbling since the handler is placed at the root of the DOM tree.

From `live()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/live/

**The handler passed to .live() is never bound to an element; instead, .live() binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree.**

and

**No handler is directly bound to the `<div>`, so the event bubbles up the DOM tree.**

From `triggerHandler()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

**Events created with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.**